# Crystal Report + VB net + Mysql How many if and ElsIf

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox, crystal-reports

I have a form with 4 comboboxes and a button.  This button search the 4 values of the comboboxes:

1. License
2. Maker
3. Type
4. Scale

How can I select 2 of the values without the other two, for example, Maker and Scale?  I need to be able to search and display any value selected. Right now, I have only this code, but I need the 4 values. What do I do to change that with out, if combox1 = query 1, if combo 1 + combo 3 = query 3, etc......

```vb
If ComboBox1.Text = "All" Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Try
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from product order by id_maker asc, id_types asc, id_scale asc,name asc"
            Dim dscmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, con)
            dscmd.Fill(ds, "PAYPRODUCTTOTAL")
            con.Close()
            Dim cryds As New All_Database_Report
            cryds.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryds
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text <> "All" Then
        If ComboBox2.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Maker", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Type", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Scale", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Else
                Try
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    Dim query As String
                    p(0) = New MySqlParameter("@License", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(0).Value = ComboBox1.Text
                    p(1) = New MySqlParameter("@Maker", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(1).Value = ComboBox2.Text
                    p(2) = New MySqlParameter("@Type", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(2).Value = ComboBox3.Text
                    p(3) = New MySqlParameter("@Scale", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(3).Value = ComboBox4.Text
                    query = "select * from product WHERE license = @License AND id_maker = @Maker AND id_types =  @Type AND id_scale =  @Scale order by id_maker asc, id_types asc, id_scale asc,name asc"
                    Dim dscmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, con)
                    dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(0))
                    dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(1))
                    dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(2))
                    dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(3))
                    dscmd.Fill(ds, "PAYPRODUCTTOTAL")
                    con.Close()
                    Dim cryds As New All_Database_Report
                    cryds.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryds
                    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        End If

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an if statement to check if the value is empty if it is empty then do not add the parameters to the command.

As for the SQL you can add Where 1=1 then wrap each field/value in an If statement to check for blank.  By adding in the 1=1 it will make all the field/values format the same AND FIELD = VALUE

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "All" Then
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            Try
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                Dim query As String
                query = "select * from product order by id_maker asc, id_types asc, id_scale asc,name asc"
                Dim dscmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, con)
                dscmd.Fill(ds, "PAYPRODUCTTOTAL")
                con.Close()
                Dim cryds As New All_Database_Report
                cryds.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryds
                CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text <> "All" Then
            If ComboBox2.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Maker", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Type", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Scale", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Else
                Try
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    Dim query As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

                    p(0) = New MySqlParameter("@License", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(0).Value = ComboBox1.Text
                    p(1) = New MySqlParameter("@Maker", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(1).Value = ComboBox2.Text
                    p(2) = New MySqlParameter("@Type", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(2).Value = ComboBox3.Text
                    p(3) = New MySqlParameter("@Scale", MySqlDbType.String)
                    p(3).Value = ComboBox4.Text

                    With query
                        .Append("select * from product WHERE 1=1 ")
                        If p(0).Value <> "" Then .Append(" AND license = @License ")
                        If p(1).Value <> "" Then .Append(" AND id_maker = @Maker ")
                        If p(2).Value <> "" Then .Append(" AND id_types =  @Type ")
                        If p(3).Value <> "" Then .Append(" AND id_scale =  @Scale ")
                        .Append(" order by id_maker asc, id_types asc, id_scale asc,name asc ")
                    End With

                    Dim dscmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(query.ToString(), con)
                    If p(0).Value <> "" Then dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(0))
                    If p(1).Value <> "" Then dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(1))
                    If p(2).Value <> "" Then dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(2))
                    If p(3).Value <> "" Then dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p(3))
                    dscmd.Fill(ds, "PAYPRODUCTTOTAL")
                    con.Close()
                    Dim cryds As New All_Database_Report
                    cryds.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryds
                    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        End If

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Comment: Ok. I try later...Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks but i have only one problem, "StringBuilder" is not defined. ?? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Imports System.Text should help :)

Comment: You don't have to use StringBuilder you can just join the strings together.  Note: always make sure to include a space at the beginning and the end when piecing an sql statement together.  " And field = value " vs "and field = value"

Comment: OK just insert Imports System.Text

Comment: Thanks EJD. You´re help is amazing. Now i can delete " ElseIf ComboBox1.Text <> "All" Then
            If ComboBox2.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Maker", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Type", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Select a Scale", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Else" by Else